# python unittest error raised by submodule

Tags: python, exception, python-unittest

MyModule.py

```
import uno

class MyModule():
    def myModuleMethode(self. args):
        try:            
            uno.callMethod(args)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return "error string"
```

test_mymodule.py

```
import my_module
import unittest

# unittest setup

    def test_MyModuleMyModuleMethod(self):
        with self.assertRaises(NoSuchElementException) as cm:
            MyModuleMethod(make, sure, the, method, call, fails, with, these, params)
        self.assertEqual(str(cm.exception), "error string")
```

the interpreter spits out:

```
>>> MyModuleMethod(make, sure, the, method, call, fails, with, these, params)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.NoSuchElementException
```

and running the test file from konsole, it returns:

```
Me@MyPrecious:$ python -m unittest -v test_mymodule
```

> ### testmumblemumble:ERROR
>
> ### ERROR: mumbledemumbling_moremublemumbelin_test (mymodule_test.MyModuleTest)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/path/to/where/lib/python3/site-packages/MyModyle/test/mymodule_test.py",
> line 207, in test_MyModuleMyModuleMethod
> with self.assertRaises(NoSuchElementException) as cm: NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined
>
> ---

**The issue and question is** that the uno module spits out an internally defined exception, and I cannot seem to catch it ...

Comment: Where does `MyModule` get it from? If worst comes to worst you can catch the general `Exception`.

Comment: it is defined in the uno module, how do I catch the general exception?

Comment: But presumably MyModule imports it, why can the tests? And you catch it with... `self.assertRaises(Exception)`

Comment: AttributeError: module 'uno' has no attribute 'NoSuchElementException' pppppffff stuck in a loop, uf i do not import uno, test doesnt know, If I do it gets attribute error

Comment: What code does that correspond to, exactly? Please give a [mre], the code you've posted isn't consistent.

Comment: impossible, sorry, the uno module is so complex, it needs to open a file and connect via socket, and the check if certain sheet exists and returns a NoSuchElementException

Comment: it was worth a try though